# angular-chart.js: showing lines on eachother, in case of equal Y coordinates (stepped linechart)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, chart.js, angular-chart

I have a stepped line chart in angular-chart.js (http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/), which is showing some data, with y coordinates (these are statuses of processes) and seconds(x coordinates).

[Stepped line chart picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0iyA.png)

My problem is, if I have two process, with the same x and y value, just one of them is visible. 
What I want to reach is, that all my data should be visible in case of equal values.

```
<div>
     <canvas id="mychart"
             class="chart chart-line"
             chart-data="vm.data"
             chart-series="vm.series"
             chart-options="vm.options"
             chart-colors="vm.colors"
             width="350"
             height="200">
     </canvas>
</div>
```

Data looks like this:

```
data: [[{x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 1, y: 1}], [{x: 0, y: 2}, {x: 1, y: 1}]]
```

options:

```
options = {
        animation: {
            duration: 0
        },
        hover: {
            mode: null
        },
        tooltips: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        elements: {
            line: {
                tension: 0,
                stepped: true,
                fill: false,
                borderDash: []
            }
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom',
                ticks: {
                    reverse: true,
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    stepSize: 1,
                    max: MAX_VALUE,
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    min: -1,
                    stepSize: 1,
                    maxRotation: 45,
                    minRotation: 45,
                    max: 10
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    };
```

**Does anyone have any idea, how to solve this issue?**

Comment: Isn't one line under another but still visible though? If you hover over one of those dots it should display single toolTip with more than one key.

Comment: My problem is, it changes in every second, so the tooltip is just annoying.

Comment: Is making each line different thickness an option?

Comment: I'll give a shot to see how it looks like, thanks :)